# JdbcPollingChannelAdapter and IntegrationFlow No rolling back the update when an exception occurs in the Integraion flow messages

Tags: jdbc, spring-integration, spring-jdbc, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-dsl

My use case is that I have got a spring boot application with a JdbcPollingChannelAdapter to fetch data from a postgresql database, updating the fetched rows and moving foreward with message flow (using IntegrationFlowBuilder) to process some transform to the ResultSet and publish the results to RabbitMQ.
JdbcPollingChannelAdapter is configured to fetch data each 60 seonds with a `select for update` query followed by an update query to flag the status form **NEW** to **PUBLISH** status:
The sql query :`select * from table where status= 'NEW' order by tms_creation limit 100 for update;`

The update query : `update table set cod_etat = 'PUBLISH', tms_modification = now() where id in (:id)`
Also, there is no Max Row per Poll to fetch data, which means that the jdbc poller will execute the sql request as many time as data (with status NEW) is present.

**First issue:** I stop my RabbitMQ and let my microservice running, the JdbcPollingChannelAdapter fetch the first ResultSet pass them through the Message flow and process the update. The message flow process the resultSet to send them through a channel to rabbitMQ(using spring cloud stream). The send fail and no Rollback has occured which means that the resultSet has been flagged as published.
I Have been loking around in documentation to figure out what I have missed. So any help would be appreciate.

**Second issue:** I run 3 instances of my application on PCF, and handle the concurrent access to the rows in the datable. My transaction and the select for update query in The JdbcPollingChannelAdapter suppose to get **Row-level Lock Modes** for the current transaction as per sql query (select for update). But what is happening is that more than one instance could get the same rows which is supposed to be managed by the current lock. Thus, it leads to multiple instances handling the same data and publishing them multiple times.

My code is as

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ProprietesSourceJdbc.class)
@Component
public class KafkaGuy {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaGuy.class);

    private ProprietesSourceJdbc proprietesSourceJdbc;
    private DataSource sourceDeDonnees;
    private DemandeSource demandeSource;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public KafkaGuy(ProprietesSourceJdbc proprietesSourceJdbc, DemandeSource demandeSource, DataSource dataSource, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.proprietesSourceJdbc = proprietesSourceJdbc;
        this.demandeSource = demandeSource;
        this.sourceDeDonnees = dataSource;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource<Object> jdbcSourceMessage() {
        JdbcPollingChannelAdapter jdbcSource = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(this.sourceDeDonnees, this.proprietesSourceJdbc.getQuery());
        jdbcSource.setUpdateSql(this.proprietesSourceJdbc.getUpdate());
        return jdbcSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fluxDeDonnees() {
        IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder = IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcSourceMessage());
        flowBuilder
                .split()
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, message ->
                        message.getHeaders().get("sequenceNumber")
                                + " événements publiés sur le bus de message sur "
                                + message.getHeaders().get("sequenceSize")
                                + " événements lus (lot)")
                .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("type", "payload.typ_evenement"))
                .publishSubscribeChannel(publishSubscribeSpec -> publishSubscribeSpec
                        .subscribe(flow -> flow
                                .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                                .transform(kafkaGuyTransformer())
                                .channel(this.demandeSource.demandePreinscriptionOuput()))
                        );
        return flowBuilder.get();
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaGuyTransformer kafkaGuyTransformer() {
        return new KafkaGuyTransformer();
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(this.proprietesSourceJdbc.getTriggerDelay(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(trigger);
        pollerMetadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(proprietesSourceJdbc.getMaxRowsPerPoll());
        return pollerMetadata;
    }

    public class KafkaGuyTransformer implements GenericTransformer<Message, Message> {

        @Override
        public Message transform(Message message) {
            Message<String> msg = null;
            try {
                DemandeRecueDTO dto = objectMapper.readValue(message.getPayload().toString(), DemandeRecueDTO.class);
                msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(dto.getTxtDonnee())
                        .copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
                        .build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

I am new In spring integration and sorry if is not well explained. Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks good and should be as you have described. Only the problem I see that there is no transaction configured for the `IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcSourceMessage())`.

Consider to `PollerMetadata.setAdviceChain()` with a `TransactionInterceptor`.

Another way is to use a `PollerSpec` with its `transactional()` option.

This way you won't use local data base transactions which are committed exactly after return from the `ResultSet` processing. With transaction on the application level there is not going to be a commit until you exit a thread.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks Artem, that fixed the issue and worked fine.

Comment: Still get a problem when adding PlatformTransactionManager. I have an integration tests in my spring boot app using spring data jpa and H2 data base aside. inserting data is not working anymore When using the added bean in my class.?

Comment: What doesn't it mean? Is that really related to this question? Isn't a `DataSourceTransactionManager` enough for you to make everything transactional?

Comment: Not related to this question. I have A JPA entity in one module which using Spring Data to save and fetch data. When running my integration tests with an in memory H2 database. Data is not inserted anymore when using DataSourceTransactionManager. which makes tests to fail

Comment: Well, you can have several transaction managers and point explicitly which one and where to use.

Comment: I don't think `JpaTransactionManager` is going to use with this plain `JdbcTemplate`...

Comment: Actually my springboot app has an hexagonal architecture. So The above class is in a separate module. And in another module called data access is using spring data. In my Spring integration tests I am loading the application with a JpaTransactionManager (just for my integration test) but still not working. My repository does not perform the insert.

Comment: Are you familiar with this: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testing-tx ? Doesn't your story deserve a separate SO thread already?